# How do i apply a PerspectiveTransform to graphics object or image?

Tags: java, image-processing, jai

I'm trying to draw a square image into a trapezoid using the Java Advanced Imaging API; However after creating a PerspectiveTransform I am unsure how I would go about applying it to a graphics object or image.

Comment: Cross posted: http://www.java-forums.org/java-2d/47818-render-image-into-given-quadrilateral.html#post230234

Answer (score 0):

When you apply a JAI operation, get `RenderedOp`, whichever operation (PerspectiveTransform, Scale...) as result. This represents the operation in a chain if you apply several operations to the same image, so the next operation is applied over the `RenderedOp` and so on. Finally, you need to draw it, so:

1) Convert it to `RenderedImage` in order to apply all calculations to the final image. Use something like:

```
new BufferedImage(renderedOp.getColorModel(), renderedOp.copyData(), false, null);
```

2) Draw the image onto a `Graphics` using something like:

```
Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D)graphics; // Convert the graphics received to Graphics2D to get more operations.
graphics2D.drawRenderedImage(renderedImage, new AffineTransform());
```